# R how to output date as row.name in write.table()

Tags: r

I try to use write.table() to output build-in dataset EuStockMarkets.
EuStockMarkets is like this.

[image: code_picture]

However, when I used write.table(EuStockMarkets, ".txt") to output a text file, the dates disappeared.

[image: txt_picture]

I want to know how to print the dates with the data as row name?

To display the first picture, just type *EuStockMartkets* in the console.

```
write.table(EuStockMarkets, "...\euStockMarkets.txt", sep="\t", na = ".", row.names = TRUE, col.names = TRUE)
```

And my code is like this.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This community has a few [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [norms](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and following them will help you get a good answer to your question.  In particular, it’s best to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (a minimum, complete, and verifiable example).  Good advice for R-specific MVCEs is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) and [here](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/reprex-dos-and-donts.html).

Comment: Please add your code, else nobody can help you. Thanks!

Comment: Also, it’s best to avoid using images of code/data and [here’s why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Note that you can quickly get your data out of your R session and onto SO by calling `dput(my_df)` and copy/pasting the result.  If your data are large, do `dput(head(my_df))`.

Comment: I've edit my questions. Thank you very much.